# Want remove the word "Connected" while connecting to the sql plus and taking the output in the csv file

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I am writing the shell script to move the data from the SQL plus to Sybase. But before that I need to take the output to the csv file which I have done.

I want to remove the "Connected." word form the csv file so that I can have the data columns only so that I can read the data from the file and insert it in the sybase.

I tried searching but unable to find a proper command. I have used the following but none worked for me.

```
set heading off
set echo off
set feedback off
```

Comment: Show us the source of your shell script with the command you're running, (a sample of) the output you're getting, and an example of the output you'd *like* to be getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I used `/dev/null` for silencing all the notifications and the spool command to output the result. It works great.